# How to sum random rows column in where clause SQL

Tags: sql-server

I have a stored procedure that selects a number of random rows from a table based on a parameter and I need to run this in a loop so it constantly selects random rows until the sum of them is accepted

So far I haven't started the loop yet because I can't figure out how do i use sum of a column as a condition

```
GO
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.spx_SELECT_RandomLocalizacoes') IS NOT NULL
DROP PROCEDURE spx_SELECT_RandomLocalizacoes
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE spx_SELECT_RandomLocalizacoes
        @Localizacoes_Max int,
        @Filtro int,
        @Armazem int
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON  

        SELECT TOP (@Localizacoes_Max) * FROM xInventario 
        WHERE Armazem = @Armazem AND SUM(Quantidade) > @Filtro
        ORDER BY newid()

END
```

The final result should be a procedure that returns me the rows that obey the condition

**EDIT:**

I forgot to add that, I have to return the select statement with the random rows with the same seed so i can only do that query once

Answer (score 1):

you can treat your query as a sub-query and SUM it, then apply whatever logic you are looking for

```
if (SELECT SUM(Randoms.YourField)   FROM (SELECT TOP (@Localizacoes_Max) * FROM xInventario 
        WHERE Armazem = @Armazem AND SUM(Quantidade) > @Filtro 
        ORDER BY newid()) AS Randoms) = @Target
BEGIN

  --do stuff

END
```

Comment: Seems the way to go but i think i need to store the query in a variable so i can return the rows with the same seeds generated